# Strange Python crash in _PyMainInterpreterConfig_Read

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use Linux (Ubuntu 19.04 x64, Python 3.7.x), and text editor CudaText 1.80.0 x64. If I write specific config line to `settings/user.json`, then CudaText crashes on start with Python error:

```
Fatal Python error: _PyMainInterpreterConfig_Read: memory allocation failed
ValueError: character U+75002f is not in range [U+0000; U+10ffff]
```

The line which causes this, in settings/user.json, is "ui_toolbar_theme" with such value. (First line is needed to use Python engine on Linux).

```
{
  "pylib__linux": "libpython3.7m.so.1.0",
  "ui_toolbar_theme": "cyan_24x24"
}
```

I cannot find `_PyMainInterpreterConfig_Read` in CudaText sources so I guess that CudaText is not guilty. It is some Py issue. How to avoid it?

- I deleted all additional CudaText plugins. I also deleted that "cyan" icon set from "data" so actually app doesn't load that icon set.
- I think it is not for SuperUser site, it is Python engine issue.
- If i edit string to "flat_24x24", crash still here. If i edit string to "default_24x24", no crash.
- No special chars in string, I typed it by hands too.

Comment: Does it still happen if you remove the `"ui_toolbar_theme"` line entirely? My first instinct is that it's misinterpreting some of the text as a unicode character string, though off the top of my head I don't know which.

Comment: Are there any hidden/unprintable characters in that string?

Comment: If i edit string to "flat_24x24", crash still here. If i edit string to "default_24x24", no crash.
No special chars in string, I typed it by hands too.

Comment: better search for Py_SetPath(). This bug is maybe related to bad handling of wchar_t and path settings just before Py_Initialize().